# Как через EventSystem, что бы он всегда выбирал кнопку, для управления UI Button через клавиатуру

Tags: unity3d

Я делаю через скрипт, что то вроде

```
public class SelectedButton : MonoBehaviour
{
private int quantity = 0;

private void Update()
{
    if (quantity == 0)
    {
        quantity++;
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject);
    } 
}
```

}

Это выглядит просто ужасно как по мне, у меня есть меню и после появляется другое, нужно что бы когда я убираю 1 меню для 2 меню сразу же для FirstSelected выставлялся верхняя кнопка. Просто то что я делаю мне кажется это не правильным и не красивым со стороны кода. Да и появляются баги. Как сделать что бы всегда при появлении какого либо меню, EventSystem был сконцентрирован на кнопках.Что бы можно было двигать клавишами, а не мышкой.

Comment: Все теряют мысль спустя 5 слов читая это?

Comment: Вот я и говорю это просто ужасно, я хочу понять логику, потом уже собирался рефакторить, quantity это количество сколько раз надо установить EventSystem объект, скрипт весит на кнопке, и надо что бы при появлении объекта он сразу же устанавливал в EventSystem себя ввиде выбора.

Comment: Просто как сделать, что бы при появлении какого либо UI с кнопками, EventSystem сразу указывал на кнопки, что бы можно было двигать по кнопкам с клавиатуры. Код в основном здесь не для этого, я хочу понять как это сделать

Comment: Указывать через скрипт на кнопку которую нужно указывать, ну мне кажется не очень, может есть какой то предусмотренный способ Unity, или может уже изобрели велосипед по этому повод, лишь надо что бы при появлении UI с Button EventSystem всегда выбирал в FirstSelected кнопку которая находится в меню